# Flutter crash in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, flutter2.0

getting this exception on release mode

> Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot

Flutter version 2.0.4

Comment: I have same issue in my case i have android and flutter combined code. First of all 2-3 activities from android that is running good after that call flutter activity then system crash and give me  

Error while initializing the Dart VM: Precompiled runtime requires a precompiled snapshot

This is only in release mode in debug mode every thing is fine and faced this only after update flutter version 2.0.4 before that on 1.22.4 it was working.

Comment: Still no answer for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Switch Flutter to master branch